# Can an exception handler write to the stream opened in an enclosing with-block?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, exception, with-statement

I would like to do something roughly like this<sup>1</sup>:

```
with open(somepath, 'w') as writer:

    def handler(*args, **kwargs):
        print(format_exception_info(*args, **kwargs), file=writer)
        sys.__excepthook__(*args, **kwargs)

    sys.excepthook = handler

    return do_stuff()
```

In other words, if an exception gets raised during the execution of `do_stuff`, I would like the program to write some information about the exception to the write-stream `writer`.

The above won't work as written; as far as I can tell, it appears that if an exception is raised during the execution of `do_stuff`, the `__exit__` method associated `with` block will be executed (thereby closing `writer`) before `sys.excepthook` (i.e. `handler`) gets invoked.

Is there some way to modify this code (still preserving the `with`-block) so that `writer` is still open when `handler` runs?

**NB:** I am interested in the answer to this question for both Python 3.x and Python 2.7.x.

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> The variable `somepath` and the functions `format_exception_info` and `do_stuff` mentioned in this snippet are supposed to be defined elsewhere.  I hope that their names are suggestive enough to describe what they stand for.</sup>